# Appending images to a div on different select box options

Tags: jquery

I have 4 select boxes that should do the following:

You should only be able to choose one option between all 3 select boxes, so only one select box can contain a value at a time - **Now this part works.**

**The part that does NOT work and that breaks the above functionality:**
When ever you choose a value in one of the select boxes, an image should be appended to an empty div: Each select box represents a person(except the 1st select) and when you select that person, his image should appear in the div (#reps).

How do i do this?

Here is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2DzUV/57/)

```
<select>
    <option>---</option>
    <option>Office</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<select>
    <option>---</option>
    <option>Mark</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<select>
    <option>---</option>
    <option>Magnus</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<select>
    <option>---</option>
    <option>Adii</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />

<div id="reps">

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var a = 'http://woothemes.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/themes/woo/images/team/';
var x = 'mark.jpg';
var y = 'magnus.jpg';
var z = 'adii.jpg';

$('select').eq(0).find('option').eq(1).attr('selected','selected');

$('select').on('change', function () {
    $('select').not(this).val("---");

    //the problem area below that breaks my cod as well, remove to see
    if(this.eq() == 1){
        $('#reps').append('<img src="'a + x'" />');
    }
    else if(this.eq() == 2){
        $('#reps').append('<img src="'a + y'" />');
    }

    else if(this.eq() == 3){
        $('#reps').append('<img src="'a + z'" />');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the string concat of the img tag (some + sign missing).

The real problem is the search of the current element, you can check if the current element is a particular isntance by using [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element,
>   or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements
>   matches the given arguments.

Code:

```
if ($('select').eq(0).is($(this))) {
    $('#reps').append('<img src="' + a + x + '" />');
} else if ($('select').eq(1).is($(this))) {
    $('#reps').append('<img src="' + a + y + '" />');
} else if ($('select').eq(2).is($(this))) {
    $('#reps').append('<img src="' + a + z + '" />');
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/jjyh5/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, there were some minor jQuery errors and i've fixed them.

http://jsfiddle.net/2DzUV/64/

```
var a = 'http://woothemes.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/themes/woo/images/team/';
var x = 'mark.jpg';
var y = 'magnus.jpg';
var z = 'adii.jpg';

$('select').eq(0).find('option').eq(1).attr('selected','selected');

$('select').on('change', function () {
    $('select').not(this).val("---");
    $('#reps').empty();
    //the problem area below that breaks my cod as well, remove to see
    if($(this).index() == 0){        
        $('#reps').append('<img src="'+a+x+'"/>');
    }
    else if($(this).index() == 3){
        $('#reps').append('<img src="'+a+y+'"/>');
    }

    else if($(this).index() == 6){
        $('#reps').append('<img src="'+a+z+'" />');
    }
});
```

Please note: To find out the eq element which is changed you need to use the `.index()` method. The Index of your selects are 0,3 and 6 because of the the `<br/>` tags. The `<br/>` tags are also being counted. if you need index such as 0,1,2 you will need to remove the `<br/>` tags from your html code :) and position the select boxes using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just reference the image name into the option value ?

HTML

```
[...]
<select>
    <option>---</option>
    <option value="adii.jpg">Adii</option>
</select>
[...]
```

JS

```
[...]
$('select').on('change', function () {
    $('select').not(this).val("---");
    $('#reps').html('<img src="' + a + $(this).val() + '" />');

});
```

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/2DzUV/61/

Answer (score -1):

Append adds the html after the selected one. 
Did you try to use `$('#reps').html('<img src="'a + x'" />');` instead ?

Here is an example :
http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Nope that does not work either. The whole append image code breaks my original function of allowing only one option...Did you play with my fiddle?

Comment: and actually, you are wrong, that is not what append does:http://api.jquery.com/append/. "Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements."